# incompatibilities while installing ta-lib (Mac)

Tags: python, ta-lib

hi I am trying to install ta-lib on my Mac (using conda) and I am getting incompatibilities errors. checked other questions on SO but couldn't get an answer. can someone help please?

```
(Pk) prasads-imac:Pk prasadkamath$ conda install -c quantopian ta-lib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                      failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                                                                                                                                                                
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - ta-lib -> python[version='2.7.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package pip conflicts for:
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.7 -> pip
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
Package certifi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
Package setuptools conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are currently using an environment with python V 3.7.

The conda formula for this one does not contain an updated version of TA-lib for python 3.7. Instead, you could create a new environment with python 3.5 and run the same code in the terminal.

Alternatively, you can also install pip in your current environment and then follow instruction at this website: https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib.